# xlsxwriter conditional formatting on a union of ranges

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a union of ranges in excel, however, it does not seem to be working. This is the code I am trying to execute (*ws* is the excel writer's worksheet):

```
ws.conditional_format('K13:O27, K35:037', {'type': '3_color_scale',
                                       'min_color': '#F8696B',
                                       'mid_color': 'white',
                                       'max_color': '#63BE7B',
                                       'mid_value': '0',
                                       'mid_type': 'num'})
```

but I am getting the following error message:

```
cell_1, cell_2 = args[0].split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Does anyone know if this is doable, and if yes - what is the format of the union operator I should use on my cell_range input variable?

Comment: You can only use **one** range, change to `.conditional_format('K13:O27, ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer stovfl. However, I am trying to apply conditional color scaling on a union of two ranges. Obviously, the final formatting won't necessarily be the same if I apply two separate conditional color scalings, or if I do it on the union of the ranges.

Comment: *"won't be the same if I apply two separate conditional color scalings"*: So, adjust your `'min/max_color'` range. E.g. the first range ends with `'#A3BE7B'` and use this as `'min_color'` for second range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is possible using the `conditional_format()` `multi_range` parameter:

```
ws.conditional_format('K13:O27', {'type': '3_color_scale',
                                  'min_color': '#F8696B',
                                  'mid_color': 'white',
                                  'max_color': '#63BE7B',
                                  'mid_value': '0',
                                  'mid_type': 'num',
                                  'multi_range': 'K13:O27 K35:037'})
```

See the `multi_range` section of the XlsxWriter docs on [Working with Conditional Formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html?highlight=multi_range).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - Thanks!